# First smart phone, activating droid incredible question

Tags: htc-droid-incredible, verizon

I just bought a used Droid Incredible off Amazon and would like to play around with it. Its asking me to call a number and activate it. I am hesitant to activate it before I go to the Verizon store to upgrade from my flip phone to this smart phone, using the same phone number. If I activate it will that mess anything up? I know very little about cell phone service.

Answer (score 0):

Wait till till go to the Verizon store. They can set up your number on your new phone while they desk with your phone transfer.